# How to optimize iterating over aggregated days and location?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a data frame that consists of events with their date, location_id and another one with location_id and a sorted index.

```py
data = pd.DataFrame(data={'date':['2020-01-01', '2020-01-02','2020-01-01'], 
                   'location_id':[100, 2500, 56029],
                  })
data

         date  location_id
0  2020-01-01          100
1  2020-01-02         2500
2  2020-01-01        56029

location = pd.DataFrame(data={'location_id':[100,2500,56029]}, index=[1,2,3])

location

   location_id
1          100
2         2500
3        56029
```

I want the count the number of events for each location by day and then use the `location_id` on another data frame to eventually create a numpy array for each day that contain the number of events and use the array for another equation I have. So for instance if there are 1000 locations, then with the present example, I want a numpy array that for `2020-01-01` I get an array of zeros everywhere except row 1 and 3 which will be 1 and similarly on `2020-01-02` row 2 will be 1 and zero everywhere else.

Here is my workaround for now:

```py
NumberOfLocations = location.shape[0]
NumberOfEvents_atLocations = np.zeros((NumberOfLocations,1))

df = data

Format = '%Y-%m-%d'

start_date = datetime.datetime.strptime(min(df.date), Format)
end_date = datetime.datetime.strptime(max(df.date), Format)
daterange = pd.date_range(start_date, end_date)

for t in daterange:
    date = t.date().strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
    NumberOfEvents_atLocations = np.zeros((NumberOfLocations,1))
    NumberOfEvents_atLocations_df = pd.DataFrame(NumberOfEvents_atLocations, location.location_id)
    if not(df[df.date == date].empty):
        NumberOfEvents_atLocations_index = df[df.date == date].location_id.value_counts().index
        NumberOfEvents_atLocations_df.loc[NumberOfEvents_atLocations_index] = np.vstack(df[df.date == date].location_id.value_counts().values)
    else:
        NumberOfEvents_atLocations_index = 0

    del NumberOfEvents_atLocations_index
```

This works fine; however, this code is very slow since I have data for over 15 years. Here are few points about data I work for now:

- In `data` data frame, date, location_id and index are not sorted; however, they can be sorted of course if needed.
- There might be days where no event was recorded that is why there is
  an if-else statement in the body of for-loop.
- location_id are not meaningful. They are simply identifiers.
- The index of `location` data frame is in order and that is why I use
  it for creating numpy array.
- One solution to make this process faster might be to store the number of
  events in a separate data frame by dates. However the data set I am
  working with has data down to hour and eventually I may divide days
  to 6-hour/12-hour periods, so I would like to have that flexibility for future implementation.

I feel like this implementation can be improved a lot. I have already looked into `df.grouby().size()`; however, it seems it may need two for-loops, one for date and one for location_id.

I can provide more details if needed.

Comment: I'd use `df.groupby([df.date.dt.date, 'location_id']).agg({'location_id': 'count'})`. With this, the `date` column should be a proper datetime format. Don't string format it.